# Any Kalman Filter implementation in C for GPS + Accelerometer?

Tags: c, gps, outliers, kalman-filter, imu

I'm trying to rectify GPS readings using Kalman Filter. I already have an IMU with me which has an accelerometer, gyro, and magnetometer.

I've tried looking up on Kalman Filters but it's all math and I can't understand anything. Any example codes would be great!

EDIT: In my project, I'm trying to move from one LAT,LONG GPS co-ordinate to another. I'd like to get smooth GPS reading instead of the ones showing displacement even when there's no movement. I am thinking of using an accelerometer to check displacement and remove GPS reading outliers. However, from what I've read, a Kalman Filter is used for such an application. But every example of it I've found is in some high-level language. It would be great if there's something in C I can build on. Thanks!

Comment: I my opinion, Kalmann Filters are beyond what can be understood with example code. You will have to find a dedicated tutorial. Actually a book or appropriate lecture is probably required.

Comment: You didn't really describe what you're trying to achieve exactly, or which problem you're trying to solve. Therefore, just some code example is most likely going to be useless for you, and thus a waste of time for everyone...

Comment: NOTE: kalmann filters are for operating on the raw satellite data, the result is the data for the NEMA messages passed to your application

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a code example, without specifying any details, so it's hard to help you further.

You could try browsing github by searching for "kalman", and limit your query to C code.

https://github.com/search?l=C&q=kalman&type=Repositories

Comment: I've updated my post. Let me know if what I'm thinking is correct :)